# É possível mostrar visualmente outro valor para um determinado valor no banco?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-service, mongodb, nosql

Estou fazendo um ToDo e nele preciso definir prioridade (urgente, alta, média e baixa). Porém só estou conseguindo definir através de inteiro (1 é urgente, 2 é alta etc)

A dúvida é: é possível mostrar outro valor no html mas que atribua ao original no banco? Exemplo:

Se na tabela do mongodb está salvo 1, quero que no resultado da consulta pelo html apareça "URGENTE".

Se for possível, como faço?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um filtro no Angular para exibir o texto que desejar baseado no índice que você definiu para a prioridade:

```
angular
  .module('nomedoapp')
  .filter('prioridadeFilter', function() {
    return function(input) {

      if (input === 1) return 'Urgente'
      if (input === 2) return 'Alta'
      if (input === 3) return 'Média'
      if (input === 4) return 'Baixa'

      return 'Desconhecida'
    }
  })
```

Você poderia então usar esse filtro sempre que desejar exibir o texto da prioridade ao invés do valor inteiro:

```
<p>
   {{ tarefa.indice_prioridade | prioridadeFilter }}
<p>
```